# Trying to connect Django and MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, django

I've been using Django with Sqlite to learn and now wanted to start on a first real project. I'm looking to use MySQL as the database. I installed MySQLClient but keep running into this error when trying to run a migration. I've spent several hours trying to look through other posts but just can't seem to figure this out. Any direction on this out would be greatly appreciated.

My setup is:
Python - 3.8
Django - 3.0.6
MySQL - 8
MSQLClient - 1.4.6
macOS - Catalina

UPDATE: I was able to install MySQL client using pip install instead of using brew install or the tar file. Reduced the errors down to this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/usman/PycharmProjects/Webproject/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/usman/PycharmProjects/Webproject/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Users/usman/PycharmProjects/Webproject/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/usman/PycharmProjects/Webproject/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/Users/usman/PycharmProjects/Webproject/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/usman/PycharmProjects/Webproject/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from . import _mysql
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/usman/PycharmProjects/Webproject/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-38-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libmysqlclient.21.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/usman/PycharmProjects/Webproject/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-38-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Comment: Did you change the DATABASE setting in settings.py?

Comment: How did you install `mysqlclient`? Looks like you might be missing some libraries

Comment: Thanks for the response!

I did change the DATABASE settings to connect to my localhost at port 3306. 

First I installed mysqlclient using brew install then I tried downloading the client as a .tar file and setup and installed locally using the terminal. Same errors with both methods,

Comment: Any reason for not using pip to install the package?

Comment: I was running into an error when trying pip install directly. 

I came across a solution to run brew install openssl and then export 

LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/

After that, I was able to pip install mysqlclient directly. Still running into an error when trying to migrate. 

 File "/Users/usman/PycharmProjects/Webproject/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 18, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module.
Did you install mysqlclient?

Comment: Just updated the error message above after.

Answer (score 0):

After struggling with this for a few days, I finally got things to work.

Here is the process I followed, in case it helps anyone else.

1. I had been playing around with a lot of tools/installations. So, I decided to do a clean OS install.
2. Used Homebrew to install Python and set Python 3 as my default for venv following this guide: https://opensource.com/article/19/5/python-3-default-mac
3. Installed MySQL
4. Installed MySql-Client using Homebrew
5. Pip install Wheel & Pip Install mysqlclient
6. Run migration and good to go!